# How to save all files from source code of a web site?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I want to download all files (html, images, js, css) from one website. I can download each and every file separately.

I tried in Google Chrome, after clicking on the `view source`, then `ctrl + s` then saved as `sample.html` then I got one `sample.html` and also one sample folder contains all files like css, js, images etc. But again I am trying to do the same, but it's not.

So earlier how it works? Why is it not working now?

**Note:** It's only for study purpose, not for copying any website of web contents.

Comment: in chrome try file->save page as->webpage complete if you want to do it manually

Comment: Thank you for your valued answer.

Comment: This does not look like a programming question, but rather asking how to use a browser.

Comment: To download the full source code for a website you can do this command: `$ wget -r --no-parent http://websiteurl.com`

Comment: In Google Chrome, right-click on page and choose "Save as..." and "Webpage, Complete" - saves page and all references resources.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Chrome, go to options (Customize and Control, the 3 dots/bars at top right) ---> More Tools ---> save page as

```
save page as  
filename     : any_name.html 
save as type : webpage complete.
```

Then you will get `any_name.html` and `any_name folder`.

Comment: when i say full page anyway downloads one single html file without any css or js

Comment: I can not find these settings in newer Chrome. E.g. v 58.0....

Answer (score 30):

Try [Winhttrack](http://www.httrack.com/)

> ...offline browser utility.
>
> It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted downloads. HTTrack is fully configurable, and has an integrated help system.
>
> WinHTTrack is the Windows 2000/XP/Vista/Seven release of HTTrack, and WebHTTrack the Linux/Unix/BSD release...